# How to write a custom method for an ActiveRecord using 'acts_as_<something>'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to use some custom method for an ActiveRecord so that I can do

```
Account.<my_method_name>
```

in order to add, for example, some data to the Account object (but without to change the Account data itself).

I heard of `acts_as_<something>` statement and it is used, if I am not wrong, on building plugins, but I didn't understand if it is what I need. After adding `acts_as_<something>` maybe I have to write somewhere a method like the following in order to "act" on the current ActiveRecord on which the `<my_method_name>` is called:

```
def self.<my_method_name>
  ...
end
```

**Can someone explain me how to use that? And, if possible, can you make me a real example of its usage?**

---

*BTW*: is it better to build a plugin or write a lib in the `RAILS_ROOT/app/lib` folder?

Comment: The rails guide regarding plugins comes with a lot of information/examples about act_as. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Comment: @Amokrane Chentir But why and fo what should I use 'act_as'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at how to implement here => http://thoughtsincomputation.com/posts/coding-an-acts_as-gem-for-rails-3

For real example -> https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

The acts_as* is just way of adding behavior to a class. You can do the same by having a module ActsAs* and including this module in the class. Use the acts_as* only if you want to take arguments while adding this common behavior, otherwise just create a module and include it in the class

In the gem acts_as_taggable_on it makes sense because it takes arguments while adding the behavior.

> acts_as_taggable_on :languages,:skills

You question is similar to [rails3 gem: acts_as_something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018469/rails3-gem-acts-as-something)

Comment: I am using an engine that uses acts_as* in one model, is there anyway to remove it?